# Find every second and fourth Thursday

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query finding all dates in my table where they are a Thursday. Additionally I have been able to find the majority of the second and fourth Thursdays with this code, but sometimes it finds them, adds additional, or misses them. How could I refine this to be more accurate?

```
select Date, DATENAME(dw, Date) as 'Day'
from Appointment_Calendar
where DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Thursday' and DATEPART(day,Date) between 8 and 14 
   or DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Thursday' and DATEPART(day,Date) between 23 and 30
```

As an example this script finds 11/30 as a valid date when its the fifth Thursday.

My tables starting date is today, 8/24/2017 for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth Thursday should fall between 22nd and 28th day of the month, not 23rd and 30th. I think the change should be that simple...

So change the last line to:

```
or DATENAME(dw, Date) = 'Thursday' and DATEPART(day,Date) between 22 and 28
```

Comment: Oh wow I overlooked that, I originally started with between 22 and 29. Thank you